# Ms-Access form data export to Word

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-word

I really some help! Here's a link to a google drive zip of the access database that I'm struggling with.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwjnhQS2X7_Qamt4clFLc1Ztb2c/view?usp=sharing

So, what I have is an access database made up of a few tables and a form and some sub forms. The database info gets inputted to the tables via a form that I've created. In the example, the form is called "Database". This form exports to a word document, fields on the database go to bookmarks on the word doc. This works great so far.

In the attachment there is a "template" folder with the original word document, when the code runs it saves the completed form to the "generated" folder - works like a charm. Its a very long form for applications for liquor licenses.

So you fill in the form in access, it saves to the tables and exports the data to the word template document.

The problem that I have is that there is a subform on tab8 of the form where "director details" are saved. There can be any number of directors per application. I've managed to access the data on the subform's table, but have no idea how to loop through the data in that table to get all the information that is applicable to that application only and not data related to other applications. There is a relationship between the director details table and the application details table(this is the main table) and I'm using an application identifier field that I've created called and "ACNumber" which is unique to each application. There is a combobox on the form that selects the application and the form and subforms bring up the correct data when you select it.

The other part of the problem is how do I output this to word? A bookmark won't work, because all the fields are being repeated. Is there a way that all the data entries can be outputted to a single bookmark mabe in a textbox with the labels?

This is how it looks on the word document form:

(First person)
Full name           :   generate from item 5.4(a) from database
Physical address    :   generate from item 5.4(b) from database
Postal code         :   generate from item 5.4(c) from database
Postal address      :   generate from item 5.4(d) from database
Postal code         :   generate from item 5.4(e) from database
Identity number     :   generate from item 5.4(f) from database

(More person’s to add if needed)

Ok, I hope that describes my problem accurately.
I've tried all sorts to get this working, but its beyond me, please help guys!!!
Below is the code that I'm using: (the loop for the subform doesn't work, but one entry from that table is exported to the bookmarks currently in place)
I've tried all sorts to get this working, but its beyond me, please help guys!!!

---

```
`Private Sub ExportToWord_Click()

'Print customer slip for current customer.
  Dim appWord As Word.Application
  Dim doc As Word.Document
  Dim drst As Recordset
  Set drst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="62 Other Interests", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
  'Avoid error 429, when Word isnt open.
  On Error Resume Next
  Err.Clear
  'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.
  Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'If Word isnt open, create a new instance of Word.
    Set appWord = New Word.Application
  End If
  Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("C:\forms\templates\Form 3 - Sec 36(1).docx", , True)
  With doc
    .Bookmarks("wAppTradingNames").Range.Text = Nz(Me!AppTradingName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wAppTradingName").Range.Text = Nz(Me!AppTradingName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wCompanyName").Range.Text = Nz(Me!CompanyName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wCompanyNumber").Range.Text = Nz(Me!CompanyNumber, "")
    .Bookmarks("wRAddress1").Range.Text = Nz(Me!RAddress1, "")
    .Bookmarks("wPostalCode").Range.Text = Nz(Me!PostalCode, "")
    .Bookmarks("wRPostalAddress1").Range.Text = Nz(Me!RPostalAddress1, "")
    .Bookmarks("wRPostalCode").Range.Text = Nz(Me!RPostalCode, "")
    .Bookmarks("wDomicilium1").Range.Text = Nz(Me!Domicilium1, "")
    .Bookmarks("wDomiciliumCode").Range.Text = Nz(Me!DomiciliumCode, "")
    .Bookmarks("wDomAfter1").Range.Text = Nz(Me!DomAfter1, "")
    .Bookmarks("wDomAfterCode").Range.Text = Nz(Me!DomAfterCode, "")
    .Bookmarks("wTelOffice").Range.Text = Nz(Me!TelOffice, "")
    .Bookmarks("wTelCell").Range.Text = Nz(Me!TelCell, "")
    .Bookmarks("wTelHome").Range.Text = Nz(Me!TelHome, "")
    .Bookmarks("wFaxNumber").Range.Text = Nz(Me!FaxNumber, "")
    .Bookmarks("wEmail").Range.Text = Nz(Me!Email, "")
    .Bookmarks("wFIP").Range.Text = Nz(Me!FIP, "")
    .Bookmarks("wAppLicCat").Range.Text = Nz(Me!AppLicCat, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLiqourType").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LiqourType, "")
    .Bookmarks("wAppTradingName").Range.Text = Nz(Me!AppTradingName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wAppTradingName").Range.Text = Nz(Me!AppTradingName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLPAddress").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LPAddress, "")
    .Bookmarks("wErfNumber").Range.Text = Nz(Me!ErfNumber, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLPPostalCode").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LPPostalCode, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLPOwnership").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LPOwnership, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLPOwnersName").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpOwnersName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpOwnerAddress").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpOwnerAddress, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpRightOccupation").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpRightOccupation, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLPOccDuration").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LPOccDuration, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpPremNotErected").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpPremNotErected, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpPremAlterReq").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpPremAlterReq, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpPremAllGood").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpPremAllGood, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpBuildCommence").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpBuildCommence, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpBuildDuration").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpBuildDuration, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpTradingHours").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpTradingHours, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpRenewal").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpRenewal, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpJobsa").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpJobsa, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpJobsB").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpJobsB, "")
    .Bookmarks("wLpJobsC").Range.Text = Nz(Me!LpJobsC, "")
    .Bookmarks("wNNPRegName").Range.Text = Nz(Me!NNPRegName, "")
    .Bookmarks("wNNPRegNumber").Range.Text = Nz(Me!NNPRegNumber, "")
    .Bookmarks("wNNPRegDate").Range.Text = Nz(Me!NNPRegDate, "")
    .Bookmarks("wOtherInterests").Range.Text = Nz(drst!OtherInterests, "")
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
  End With

  Dim rst As Recordset: Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="5 Director Details", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
  'Do While Not rst.EOF
    With doc
      .Bookmarks("wPersonLabel").Range.Text = Nz(rst!PersonLabel, "")
      .Bookmarks("wFullName").Range.Text = Nz(rst!FullName, "")
      .Bookmarks("wPhAddress").Range.Text = Nz(rst!PhAddress, "")
      .Bookmarks("wPhCode").Range.Text = Nz(rst!PhCode, "")
      .Bookmarks("wPAddress").Range.Text = Nz(rst!PAddress, "")
      .Bookmarks("wPCode").Range.Text = Nz(rst!PCode, "")
      .Bookmarks("wIdNumber").Range.Text = Nz(rst!IdNumber, "")
      .Visible = True
      .Activate
      rst.MoveNext
    End With
  'Loop

  doc.SaveAs2 "C:\forms\generated\" & Me!ACNumber & "_Form 3 - Sec 36(1).docx"
  Set doc = Nothing
  Set appWord = Nothing
  Exit Sub

errHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub


`
```

Comment: There are numerous ways to go about this, the most obvious one to me would be to place a bookmark and add a table on that bookmark. Review [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1702h4a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to create a table, and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkf9d64e.aspx) to add values to the cells of the table. You could also include the table in your template, and add row to the table in the loop. If you're having trouble with this, ask a new specific question about it. Your question is very broad.

Comment: Also I would use Word Mail Merge functionality instead of one-by-one coping values from recordset to bookmarked text.

Comment: Thanks Eric! That answers the "how to format the output data on the word form" nicely, I'll use a table. Now i need to wrap my head around how to loop through the data in subform table to select and output the data related to the specific application. This subform's table will hold data related to many individual forms/license applications, I need to get only the entries related to the specific application only. I have no idea how to code this.

Comment: You can just loop through the subforms recordsetclone. If you ask a separate specific question (e.g. how can I loop through all records and fields in a subform), you will get a more full answer (I tend to not answer multi-barrelled questions, since people having the same problem can't find the answer if the question isn't clear).

Comment: Ok, cool. I'll ask a new question. Sorry, i'm very new to this

Answer (score 0):

This will point you to the right direction. You need to make a couple of changes though to fit your needs e.g. insert all your bookmarks, update the SQL strings and recordset fields.

You also need to make a few changes to your Word document though:

1) Add a table to hold the manager data (loop). Hide the borders if needed. 
2) Save the document as **Word Template** (.dotx)

```
Public Sub ExportToWord()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Const TemplatePath As String = "C:\forms\templates\Form 3 - Sec 36(1).dotx"

    'Data
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE [Criteria]", dbOpenSnapshot)

    'SaveAs
    Dim name_ As String
        name_ = "C:\forms\generated\" & rs![FieldName] & "_Form 3 - Sec 36(1).docx"

    'Word
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Set oWord = New Word.Application
        oWord.Visible = False

    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(TemplatePath)
    With oDoc
        .Bookmarks("Bookmark_1").Range.Text = rs![FieldName_1]
        .Bookmarks("Bookmark_2").Range.Text = rs![FieldName_2]
        .Bookmarks("Bookmark_3").Range.Text = rs![FieldName_3]
        '...
    End With

        rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    'Loop data
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE [Criteria]", dbOpenSnapshot)
    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
        End If
    End With

    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        With oDoc.Tables(1)
            .Cell(idx, 1).Range.Text = rs![FieldName_1]    '1st Column
            .Cell(idx, 2).Range.Text = rs![FieldName_2]    '2nd Column
            .Cell(idx, 3).Range.Text = rs![FieldName_1]    '3rd Column
            '...
            'add extra rows if required
            If rs.AbsolutePosition <> rs.RecordCount - 1 Then .Columns(1).Cells.Add
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
    Next idx

    'Save
    With oDoc
        .SaveAs FileName:=name_, FileFormat:=Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End With

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
        rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
        oWord.Quit
    Set oWord = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ExportToWord()"
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas! I tried that and got it mostly working. Still having issues with the table, but i'll ask another question about that specific issue if i can't get it going. Appreciate it

Comment: Just create a simple table with 7 columns and 1 row. Add the additional columns to the script and test.

Comment: I've tried all sorts but keep getting the error message - the requested member of the collection does not exist

Comment: Kostas, Thank you so much!! I've now learned how to number code lines and output the line number with the error message, also how to get my subform table data outputting to the table exactly as you said. It works perfectly. Brilliant!! Thanks!